# Java Jmap dump hanging and not creating file

Tags: java, jmap

I'm trying to get a dump on a process using jmap. The following jmap command...

```
c:\log>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\jmap" -dump:file=heap2.map 5264
```

returns

```
Dumping heap to C:\log\heap2.map ...
```

Where it sits for eternity, and does not make the file. I've tried doing the dump during normal execution, I tried making the program sift through a loop after X amount of executions, and I suspended the process VIA eclipse debug mode. Regardless, I'm unable to retrieve the dump file.